Can someone please translate this commentary by Malbim on Psalm 86:12
אודך ה' בכל לבבי, ההודאה היא על הטובות שהשיג, ולא תהיה ההודאה עם כונת מבקש, שיבקש עי"כ שיוסיף להיטיב לו שאז אינו מודה בכל לבבו, רק אודך בכל לבבי וכמ"ש למעלה (סימן ט'), וגם אכבדה שמך לעולם ע"י ספור תהלותיו וגבורותיו:

Can we ask why you're asking for random snippets of translation?

I will thank/acknowledge you, G-d, with my whole heart, the thanks (acknowledgement) is over good received (literally grasped). And this thanks is not with an intention of request, that I will request through this (thanks), meaning that there will be increased good for it (for the thanks). That such an acknowledgment is not sincere.
Only that I thank you with a whole heart like it says above (section 9), and also to honor your name always through proclaiming your praises and your might.

Welcome to MI Yodeya
loosely translated - parenthesis are my additions
The thanks (or praise) is for the good things he got and not with the intention of asking for more (meaning, David is not thanking God  with the additional intention of asking for more of the good) because then the thanks are not wholehearted. That is why the Pasuk writes "אודך בכל לבבי” (as it is a wholehearted thanks). See also what the Malbim wrote in Siman 9. Additionally the Pasuk writes "ואכבדה שמך לעולם”, I wil, forever honor your Name through the telling of His (God's)  praise and heroism (not sure if heroism is a good enough translation of גבורתיו)
